# AlarmManager time not being set correctly

Tags: android, calendar, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, timepicker

I am developing an app where I use an AlarmManager to schedule a time to open an Activity.
The chosen time is picked by a TimePicker.

Despite the time being the expected one when I call the method `when.getTime` , my activity doesn't open at the specified time.

### Getting the time

```
int hour = tp.getCurrentHour();
int min = tp.getCurrentMinute();
MedicationReminder mr = new MedicationReminder(getApplicationContext());
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
if (hour > 12) {
       c.add(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
}
mr.setReminder(new Medication(name, quant_aux, time), c);
```

### Setting alarm

```
Intent i = new Intent(mContext, MedicationReceiver.class);
i.putExtra("medName",medication.getName());
i.putExtra("medQuant",medication.getQuantity());
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext,0,i,0);
mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,when.getTimeInMillis(),pi);
```

I tried replacing `when.getTimeInMillis` by 2000 and the activity opened , so the problem is not on my broadcast receiver.

Why is this happening?

Edit: I tried to schedule for the following minute and the acitivity opened.
I tried for the next 2 minutes and the activity opened with a delay of 12-15 seconds. Tried with 5 minutes and the activity didn't open

Answer (score 0):

Try using setExact instead of set

```
...
mAlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms